# how to control apache mod-security for IP-address

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

I have mod security installed on my server. It is working for all IP addresses.

Now I need to **EXCLUDE** specific IP addresses from applying this mod-security. How can I do so? Is there a way to control it using apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here [the article](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_security-htaccess-tricks.html#disable-mod_security). The first one is IP based too. what luck.

Excerpt from that page.

---

**Disabling mod_security conditionally per IP ^**

This will make sure that you aren't processed by mod_security, but this only works if you have a static IP (Get your IP information). Just add this towards the top of your .htaccess file. before your mod_security code. Setting this variable causes the module to be disabled for this specific IP address, this means you won't run into any problems while posting yourself..

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Addr ^208.113.183.103$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off


# You can use multiple SetEnvIf directives to control it further.
# This only turns it off for your IP + a POST request method.
#
# SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^208.113.183.103$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off
# SetEnvIf Request_Method !^POST$ MODSEC_ENABLE=On
```